# How many ways to line up if daughters are on sides of mother?

Tags: permutations, combinations

If we have a mother, father, 2 daughters and 3 sons lining up for a family photo, and the mother must be between the daughters, how many ways are there for the family to line up?

I came up with ${5 \choose 3} \cdot (4!)$ (because of the positions the mother can have if there has to be one daughter on each side), and then the 3 sons and the father. Is this correct?

Comment: The number $240$ is right. I got it another way.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Do you mind telling me? I know my answer is right but I would like to know of another way to approach this. Unless it's the same as Kaj's.

Comment: It is the same as Kaj's. I tied the mother and two daughters together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**N.B.** I am assuming the problem is saying that the mother is directly between the two daughters with nobody in between.

---

I'm not convinced of your reasoning -- perhaps you could be more explicit?  The good news is that you do appear to arrive at the correct answer.

If there are two daughters, and the mother must be in the middle, then there are only $2$ different arrangements of the daughters around the mother.

From there, we can think of the $2$ daughters and the mother as a single object, together with the father and three sons who are themselves each individual objects.  So we have $5$ objects in total.  How many ways are there to place $5$ distinct objects in a line?  $5! = 120$ of course.  Multiply by $2$ from above, and we get $240$, agreeing with your answer.

Comment: I was thinking 5 choose 3 because there are only 5 possible spots for the mother to be in. She cannot be at the ends because then there would be no way for her to be sandwiched by 2 daughters. With the mother and the two daughters in place, 4 spots remain so it's 4!

Comment: Oh, very nice!  That works!